# Font?) -> some View. But why when adding modifier at siwftUI we use in this way: ext("Hello, World!").font(.body)? Why we add dot ' . '?

Tags: swift, swiftui

In the Apple Developer documentation, the font modifier is said to be declared like this:

```swift
func font(_ font: Font?) -> some View
```

But when calling it as a modifier in SwiftUI, we use in this way:

```swift
Text("Hello, World!").font(.body)
//                         ↑
//          Why do we add this dot?
```

Why do we add that dot before `body`?

Comment: Hi! I suggest you reformulate your question, what you are asking is not very clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaration

```
struct Font
```

The system resolves a font’s value at the time it uses the font in a given environment because Font is a late-binding token.

you can get standard fonts via Font static properties

```
static let largeTitle: Font
static let title: Font
static var headline: Font
static var subheadline: Font
static var body: Font
static var callout: Font
static var caption: Font
static var footnote: Font
```

Writing

```
Text("some text").font(.title)
```

is the same as

```
Text("some text").font(Font.title)
```

Comment: So is that Font struct like this? : struct Font {   static let largeTitle: Font
static let title: Font
static var headline: Font
static var subheadline: Font
static var body: Font
static var callout: Font
static var caption: Font
static var footnote: Font}

Comment: @SJLee to see more use shift-ommand-0 (or via menu Windows -> Developers Documentation) n Xcode and search  Font